# Comments from Interfaces to Implementations (resharper)

Tags: refactoring, resharper

Is it possible to write all the comments from interface fields/methods to their implementations via resharper or another tool? I know this is working when implementing an interface to a fresh class, but how can i do this when refactoring comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field/method implementations don't have doc comments then they will pick up the doc comments from the interface any way, you can see these using Resharper's quick documentation (Resharper->Edit->Show Quick Documentation... or `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`F1`).

You could also try [Ghostdoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to help with the creation of your doc comments.

I am not sure that there's any way for your implementation comments to change automatically if you update the underlying interface ones though.